# Which hook in Webpack scans the DOM?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, jsx

```
apply(compiler) {

}
```

How do I scan the DOM? I want to check all jsx files. Find all elements with a custom attribute.

I thought this is what webpack was made for - to scan files. But I can't find a way. I am suffering for several days.

```
return(
  <main>
      <div data-custom={'test'}></div>
  </main>
)
```

I have more plans. I want to assign classes to these elements, create css files for them. But I'm stuck on the first step. I can't find this element :(